# Iterating through a nested JSON Array in C# with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a block of JSON as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Section1",
    "project_id": 100,
    "configs": [
      {
        "id": 1000,
        "name": "myItem1",
        "group_id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Section2",
    "project_id": 100,
    "configs": [
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "myItem2",
        "group_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "name": "myItem3",
        "group_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 1003,
        "name": "myItem4",
        "group_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Section3",
    "project_id": 100,
    "configs": [
      {
        "id": 1004,
        "name": "myItem5",
        "group_id": 5
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

I have pulled it into Memory as a JArray.

I need to iterate through this such that I'm grabbing a list of ids and name from only the config sub-arrays.  Ideally, I'll end up with something like this:

```
1000, myItem1
1001, myItem2
1002, myItem3
1003, myItem4
1004, myItem5
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what Newstonsoft calls a JObject vs a JArray, or how to access the various parts of each of those data structures.  What I have right now is as follows:

```
foreach (JObject config in result["configs"])
{
    string id = (string)config["id"];
    string name = (string)config["name"];
    string gid = (string)config["group_id"];

    Console.WriteLine(name + " - " + id + " - " + gid);
}
```

This does not work, but I hope it illustrates what my end goal is.  I've been unable to piece together how to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is result?

Comment: The easy way is to define some classes for the structure - use the help of http://jsonutils.com - and deserialize the json into the classes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `JObject` is an object (analogous to a class):

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": true
}
```

A `JArray` is a JSON array, and contains multiple `JObject` entities:

```
[
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": true
    },
    {
        "a": 2,
        "b": true
    }
]
```

The root of a JSON document can be an object, or an array. In your case, it's an array.

The following code and [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MP0RHI) reveals that your code is fine, provided that you deserialize the document as what it is - an array.

```
string json = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Section1\",\"project_id\":100,\"configs\":[{\"id\":1000,\"name\":\"myItem1\",\"group_id\":1}]},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Section2\",\"project_id\":100,\"configs\":[{\"id\":1001,\"name\":\"myItem2\",\"group_id\":2},{\"id\":1002,\"name\":\"myItem3\",\"group_id\":2},{\"id\":1003,\"name\":\"myItem4\",\"group_id\":2}]},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Section3\",\"project_id\":100,\"configs\":[{\"id\":1004,\"name\":\"myItem5\",\"group_id\":5},]}]";
JArray obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);
foreach (var result in obj)
{
    foreach (JObject config in result["configs"])
    {
        string id = (string)config["id"];
        string name = (string)config["name"];
        string gid = (string)config["group_id"];

        Console.WriteLine(name + " - " + id + " - " + gid);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has helped immensely to clear the confusion I had about the various object types -- I sincerely appreciate your time in typing this up!

Comment: A minor clarification: A `JArray` can contain things other than `JObject`s. Specifically there could be `JValue`s if the JSON array contains strings or other non-object values. This is why the type of `result` above is the more generic `JToken` instead of `JObject`

Comment: very useful thank you, I've spent too much time to introduce myself better with Json